# Compare data before and after update php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I compare data before and after update PHP and MySQL?
If I add some data in the database that can be updated, is there a way of comparing the newly updated data with the previous data?

Comment: check out triggers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is what [TRIGGERS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) are for.

Using the `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax you can create a trigger before an UPDATE or INSERT

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table
```

or

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger_name BEFORE UPDATE ON table
```